# How to convert the result of lapply with NA items to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a list as a result of an `lapply` where the function is covered with a `trycatch` function because I have a super long list that I need my code to go through without being stopped by any error. The result looks like this:
[image]

I tried using

```
test12 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(y), nrow=length(y), byrow = T))
```

However, the data frame looks very strange and it's not really in the order I wanted. It looks like the NA [[20]] has created a break in the data frame. Anyone has experience on how to convert this list into a data frame? The expected columns are: `Title`, `Description`, and `Keywords`, and is it possible to have those NA like item [[20]] as NA value in all 3 columns? Thank you.

Comment: A reproducible example would help - or at the very least your `tryCatch` expression. You can try something like `tryCatch({ do stuff }, error=function(e) list(Title=NA, Description=NA, Keywords=NA))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R we can do

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, y)

#           Title Description Keywords
#2  Tetris Layout          NA       NA
#21 Tetris Layout          NA       NA
#3           <NA>          NA       NA
#4  Tetris Layout          NA       NA
```

**data**

```
y <- list(list(Title = "Tetris Layout", Description = NA, Keywords= NA), 
          list(Title = "Tetris Layout", Description = NA, Keywords= NA), 
          NA, 
          list(Title = "Tetris Layout", Description = NA, Keywords= NA))
```

Comment: hey @Ronak, thanks for the suggestion. I figured that I have a much longer list and for some reason ```rbind.data.frame``` doesn't work. So I changed to ```data.frame(do.call(rbind, y)``` and it's all fine. I guess maybe ```rbind.data.frame``` only works for a smaller list?

Comment: @cheklapkok that's weird...I am not sure though why... Anyway, glad that you could figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(liste,  as_tibble) %>%
          select(1:3)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Title Description Keyword
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>  
#1 xxx   xxx2        xxx3   
#2 yyy   yyy2        yyy3   
#3 <NA>  <NA>        <NA>   
#4 zzz   zzz2        zzz3
```

#### data

```
liste  <- list(list("Title" = "xxx", "Description" = "xxx2", "Keyword" = "xxx3"),
             list("Title" = "yyy", "Description" = "yyy2", "Keyword" = "yyy3"),
             NA,
             list("Title" = "zzz", "Description" = "zzz2", "Keyword" = "zzz3"))
```